# iphone: autoreleasing an object multiple times

Tags: iphone, autorelease

what happens if i retain an object multiple times. Then, will autoreleasing it once, delete it from the memory when the autorelease pool is drained; or do i have to autorelease it as many times as i retained it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autorelease schedules an object to be released **once** in some time in future (i.e. when current autorelease pool is drained). So if you retain an object several times you need to (auto)release it the same number of times to compensate that